# Algorithm to check if number x exists in matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms

I have the task to develop an algorithm which checks if a specific number x exists in an int-array[][].
Further the 2-dim array entries have following terms:

$$array[i][j] \leq array[i][j+1] \space \space \forall (i,j) \in \big\{0,...,m-1\} \times \big\{0,...,n-2\} 
$$
$$array[i][j] \leq array[i+1][j] \space \space \forall (i,j) \in \big\{0,...,m-2\} \times \big\{0,...,n-1\} 
$$

The algorithm needs to have a complexity of: $$\Theta (m+n)
$$

My first idea was first to "walk" through the first column to check if it contains a number which is bigger than the number that I am looking for.
If you try to find the number 5 in the following matrix you will realize that my thoughts do not work with this example.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 5  \\
2 & 6 & 7 \\
4 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It would be great if someone could give a hint.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start looking in the top right corner of the matrix. Then repeat the following: if you have found $x$, return `true`; if the number you found is larger than $x$, move one entry to the left; if it is smaller, move one entry down.

If this would take you out of the bounds of the matrix, return `false`.

Formally, in order to give this a running time of $\Theta(n + m)$ rather than just $\mathcal O(n + m)$, you should compute $n + m$ in unary afterwards.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Your matrix is invalid. Check the terms in my first post.

Comment: My bad. $\ \ \ $